# Climbing the stairs

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linq

A quick description on the problem I solved on codewars.com but remember I just want a small part of my solution refactored (just the `for`-loop):

**Description**

> Vasya wants to climb up a stair of certain amount of steps (Input
>   parameter 1). There are 2 simple rules that he has to stick to.
>
> Vasya can climb 1 or 2 steps at each move. Vasya wants the number of
>   moves to be a multiple of a certain integer. (Input parameter 2).
>   Task:
>
> What is the MINIMAL number of moves making him climb to the top of the
>   stairs that satisfies his conditions?
>
> Input
>
> Number of stairs: 0 < N ≤ 10000 ; Integer to be multiplied : 1 < M ≤
>   10; Output
>
> Return a single integer - the minimal number of moves being a multiple
>   of M; If there is no way he can climb satisfying condition return - 1
>   instead.

This is my C# method and I only want to refactor the `for`-loop on line 13:

```
private static int NumberOfSteps(int n , int m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n + "    " + m);
        if (m <= 1 || n <= 1) { return -1; }
        if (n == 21) { return 20; }

        var TwoSteps = Math.Ceiling(((double)n / 2)) % m != 0 ? ((n / 2) - 1) : (n / 2);
        List<int> query = Enumerable.Range(1, TwoSteps).Select(x => x = 2).ToList();
        List<int> Onesteps = Enumerable.Range(1, n - query.Sum()).Select(x => x = 1).ToList();
        query.AddRange(Onesteps);
        if (query.Count() % m == 0) { return query.Count(); }

        for (var count = 0; count <= query.Count() - 1; count++)

        {
            if (query[count] == 2)
            {
                query.RemoveAt(count);
                query.AddRange(new List<int>() { 1, 1 });
                if (query.Count() % m == 0) { Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); return query.Count(); }
            }
            if (query.Count() % m == 0) { return query.Count(); }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(-1);
        return -1;
    }
```

This is part of my code I would like to know how I could refactor it into a Linq Method Syntax statement:

```
   for (var count = 0; count <= query.Count() - 1; count++)

    {
        if (query[count] == 2)
        {
            query.RemoveAt(count);
            query.AddRange(new List<int>() { 1, 1 });
            if (query.Count() % m == 0) { Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); return query.Count(); }
        }
        if (query.Count() % m == 0) { return query.Count(); }
    }
```

Comment: @GringoJaimes As you can see the question is not well received here either.  The whole code seems really complex for what it's trying to achieve so I would suggest sanitizing the question to be a proper code review question, which is not off topic on this site. Please put some work in your question and it could become a good question with valuable answers.

Comment: @LukeG Asking for a specific refactoring request is OK here as well IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The code below is my C# Method and I only want to refactor the for-loop on line 13 I think.

Sorry but you won't only get this, because your code has a **large number of problems**.

Let us begin at the top of your code and review it to the bottom.

> Return a single integer - the minimal number of moves being a multiple of M; If there is no way he can climb satisfying condition return - 1 instead.

Why bothering with printing to the `Console` if you only need to return an integer ?
Your method should have a clear responsibility which is returning the minimal numbers of moves. Printing some values to the `Console` doesn't belong here.

---

The description of the problem clearly states that the number of stairs are in the range `0 < N ≤ 10000`.
So if the passed in parameter(s) doesn't fit into the allowed range you should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception instead of returning `-1`.

The `if (n == 21) { return 20; }` "validation" will lead to wrong results as well.

---

This

> ```
> var TwoSteps = Math.Ceiling(((double)n / 2)) % m != 0 ? ((n / 2) - 1) : (n / 2);
> ```

is hurting my eyes because it is almost unreadable. In addition , if we look a little bit down the code we see a `OneSteps` variable which is of a different type but one could assume that it is the same because of the name. So we should change the name here to `amountOfTwoSteps` and use the proper casing (`camelCase`) for the name.

This is doing the same

```
var amountOfTwoSteps = n / 2;

if (amountOfTwoSteps % m != 0)
{
    amountOfTwoSteps--;
}
```

but in a cleaner way.

---

You should be consistent in the style you use. If you use the `var` type then you should use it where ever the type of a variable is obvious from the right hand side of the assignment.

> ```
> List<int> query = Enumerable.Range(1, TwoSteps).Select(x => x = 2).ToList();
> ```

but it is a very strange way to get a list of the same number (here: `2`). You could use `Enumerable.Repeat()` instead like so

```
var query = Enumerable.Repeat(2, amountOfTwoSteps).ToList();
```

This

> ```
> List<int> Onesteps = Enumerable.Range(1, n - query.Sum()).Select(x => x = 1).ToList();
> ```

has another problem, because it iterates over all of the items of `query` by calling `Sum()` but you know that `query` has `amountOfTwoSteps` items with each item equals to `2`. So let us change `query.Sum()` to `amountOfTwoSteps * 2`.

You don't need to call `ToList()` on the enumerable because the `AddRange()` method of the `List<T>` will take an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter. You don't really need the `OneSteps` variable and the code could be changed like so

```
query.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(1, n - (amountOfTwoSteps * 2)));
```

---

You are using the `Count()` method very often, which involves for a `List<T>` a null check, a soft cast via `as` to `ICollection<T>` and again a null check` each time.

[From the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b)

```
    public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
        ....
        ....
```

If you know that the type you use is an implementation of an `ICollection<T>`, like the `List<T>` you should consider to just access the `Count` **property**.

---

> ```
> if (query[count] == 2)
> {
>     query.RemoveAt(count);
>     query.AddRange(new List<int>() { 1, 1 });
>     if (query.Count() % m == 0) { Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); return query.Count(); }
> }
> if (query.Count() % m == 0) { return query.Count(); }
> ```

If we look at the body of your `for` loop, we can see that you have some duplicated code which can be removed. I don't see a reason to remove an item of the `List`, create a `new List<T>` and use `AddRange` to add this `List` to `query` every time. This could be simplified by setting the value of the current item to `1` and adding a `1` to the list like so

```
if (query[count] == 2)
{
    query[count] = 1;
    query.Add(1);
}
if (query.Count % m == 0) { return query.Count; }
```

---

Putting all together will lead to

```
private static int NumberOfSteps(int n, int m)
{
    if (m <= 1 || m > 10) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("m"); }
    if (n < 1 || n > 10000) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n"); }

    var amountOfTwoSteps = n / 2;

    if (amountOfTwoSteps % m != 0)
    {
        amountOfTwoSteps--;
    }

    var query = Enumerable.Repeat(2, amountOfTwoSteps).ToList();
    query.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(1, n - (amountOfTwoSteps * 2)));

    if (query.Count % m == 0) { return query.Count; }

    for (var count = 0; count <= query.Count - 1; count++)
    {
        if (query[count] == 2)
        {
            query[count] = 1;
            query.Add(1);
        }
        if (query.Count % m == 0) { return query.Count; }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

which still has some magic numbers in it which should be extracted to some meaningful named constants which is for you to do.

Comment: I have refactored my code without knowing your response as well I would like to post it with what I got myself if you don't mind

Comment: @GringoJaimes if you would like to post a Follow-up question with the new code that you have written, please comment on your question with a link so that we can follow the chain of questions.

Comment: I have refactored my code and have a new question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151678/for-loop-to-query-expression-syntax

Comment: you can all go to my question again by clicking the link thanks and kind regards to all